# Where the assumption ($2^{p}-1$ is a prime number) is used in the proof of Necessity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In this page: http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Lucas-Lehmer_Test

Can anyone indicate to me where the assumption ($2^{p}-1$ is a prime number) is used in the **proof of Necessity**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote:

> Because $Q$ is prime, it will be a factor of all the binomial coefficients except the first and the last

(where $Q$ was defined to be $2^p-1$)